# Python multiplication table with loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

how to make it so that the output of this multiplication table repeat itself until 10x1 - 10x10 instead of ending at 1x10.

the code:

```
num = 1
for i in range(1,11):
        print(num, "x" ,i, "=",num*i)
```

Comment: edited my post, here is the code. num = 1 for i in range(1,11): print(num, "x",i, "=",num*i)

Comment: Copy and paste an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Use the {} icon to format it as code.

Comment: @Weaver Did you try just wrapping this loop in another loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with two loops:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    for j in range(1, 11):
        print(i, "x", j, "=", i*j)
    print("-"*20)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1x1=1
1x2=2
1x3=3
1x4=4
1x5=5
1x6=6
1x7=7
1x8=8
1x9=9
1x10=10
--------------------
2x1=2
2x2=4
2x3=6
2x4=8
2x5=10
2x6=12
2x7=14
2x8=16
2x9=18
2x10=20
--------------------
.
.
.
.
.
10x1=10
10x2=20
10x3=30
10x4=40
10x5=50
10x6=60
10x7=70
10x8=80
10x9=90
10x10=100
--------------------
```

Comment: Say, I want to use input instead of starting from one, how do I do that? let's say we inputted 2 or 4 and it will continue on until 10x10 as above.

Comment: you can do it easily like this : `for i in range(int(input()),11)` as your first for loop.

Comment: Nevermind, figured I have to put the text inside the brackets just like you would normally do.

Comment: you can do it by putting it inside the input like this: `input("Input the number here: ")`.Just a suggestion, you should start looking and reading the docs/ SO, these are very easy to find and already has answers